# Is it possible to disable PIN entry in Windows 10 when logging in with a Smart Card?

Tags: windows, smartcard, nfc

So I have a situation where I would insert a Smart Card into a PCSC Smart Card Reader for the purpose of logging into Windows. The Smart Card contains the certificate and it's not PIN encrypted. However, Windows 10 requires you to press enter after you inserted your Smart Card which is what I try to avoid as Smart Cards are a more convenient way to log into a Windows session without having to remember a password. I am well aware of the security and philosophical implication of not using a PIN/two-factor authentication so I'm expecting a clear answer.
I was looking into PIN caching but that's not the answer. The answer lies somewhere in the registry settings or Group Policy Editor.

Comment: The PIN is not required by Windows, but from the smartcard. But I don't know smartcards that do not require a PIN. May be you should better check for an alternative like one of the common 2FA USB keys. Check for example [Yubico](https://www.yubico.com/products/services-software/download/computer-login-tools/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out through [Smart Card Focus](https://www.smartcardfocus.com/downloads/Smartcard_Focus_Guide_Smartcard_Logon.pdf) and other sources that It's not possible because the PIN & Certificate resides in the actual Card as part of the PKCS#11 and Windows Smart Card Infrastructure. The PIN prompt is required as it sends it to the card and a maximum of 3 failed PIN entry attempts is enough to lock the card for security.

Answer (score 0):

"The Smart Card contains the certificate and it's not PIN encrypted." is not correct.
As George points out the PIN is used to unlock access to selected private keys and objects on the smartcard and sending wrong PIN will lock the card after a few failed tries as set on the smartcard. Certificates are normally readable without PIN by most (if not all) smartcards.

A PIV smart card (which I am very familiar with) normally has 4 certificate/private keys pairs. One for login and web authentication, one for signatures one for encryption. These three requite the PIN for access to use the private key. The 4th is for card authentication which does not require a pin, and is normally used for physical access such as a door lock, it only shows possession of the card. Some other cards could also be setup to have a private key that does not require a PIN.

It is not clear if Windows is setup to allow the use of a private key without a PIN. I would not expect it would. And I would never expect it to work remotely.

But if you have control over the card, and can change the PIN, and maybe its minimal length, you could set a PIN of 1234 or your birthday.

Smart card can be slow and if you are going to set a PIN anyway consider.

Searching for: windows 10 "smart card" logon without a PIN
shows:
From 12/04/2020:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/user-profiles-and-logon/registry-keys-smart-card-pin-caching-options-not-available

From 3/14/2017 show how to set PIN is registry, but may no longer work:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tfwKROZYViI